# Rails routing multiple controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to build an `admin` controller that need access to several other resource models.

For example

A `:shelf` controller that needs access to `:books`, `:movies`, and `:music`.  Each of which will require their own new / delete / modify actions.

Now I want to route it so I can create a new book by doing `localhost:3000/shelf/books/new`

I have already tried:

```
resources :books, :shelf=>'books'
```

but that did not work.

Would greatly appreciate anyone's help at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like

```
resources :shelf do
  resources :books
end
```

then you can make something like

```
resources :shelf do
  resources :books
  resources :movies
  ...
end
```

this will route to `localhost:3000/shelf/books`
Hope this helps!

**Update**
If you want all of the book resources under a shelf, then you can use a namespace

```
namespace :shelf do
  resources :books
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Now it works for localhost:3000/shelf/:id/books, but my shelf isn't actually a resource, how do I make it so I do not need the :id part in the url?

Comment: I actually was trying namespace and scope, namespace results in a routing error "uninitialized constant Shelf",  where as scope does work, but it also works without the /shelf.  And also, the layout seems to not apply to the book pages and I cannot seem to figure out how to add one to the books

Comment: can you post some of your shelf controller?

Comment: class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  
  def home
  end

  def dashboard
  end

  def campaigns
  end

  def analytic
  end

  def announcements
  end

  def events
  end

  def polls
  end

  def challenges
  end

  def awards
  end

  def settings
  end

  def profile
  end
end

Comment: I'd take a look at this page [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Alright I might have fixed it but I'm not sure if it is a correct solution or just hacked together piece of a lot of workaround. I used scope "shelf" do resources :books end.  I actually had another resources :books on top of my route.rb I didn't see, thats why it worked without the /shelf, and I added a books.html.erb to my layout